# Is it possible to read static text dynamically from property files in velocity template?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, velocity

greetings all
i have a java ee application (spring framework) that uses vm templates
that contains static texts like:

```
<span> hello world </span>
```

to be something like:

```
<span> <fmt:message key="hi.message" /> </span>
```

and i was wondering if it's possible to read that texts from a property file(en/fr) depending on the user locale like in JSP, so that i will use one template for all locales and the text is dynamic

Note: velocity is not my view technology used in the app, i am using it's templates in sending emails only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot use macros outside the web app, like in my case so a solution would be to use messageSource

```
model.put("messagesource", this.messagesource);
// adding this e.g. should do the trick
model.put("keyHelloCustomer", "the_key_you_use_in_your_properties_file");
model.put("noArgs", new Object[]{});
model.put("locale", yourOwnPrivateMethodToDetermineWhichLocaleToUse());
```

and in the vm:

```
${messageSource.getMessage($keyHelloCustomer, $noArgs, $locale)}
```

reference:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=82018

Comment: it works with some guys, but for me i am always getting the exception No message found under code 'null' for locale 'ar' ???? any ideas

Comment: Solved by :
model.put("myKey", "my.key");
${messageSource.getMessage($myKey, $noArgs, $locale)}

Comment: i have another problem is that when changing the locale to fr, and i have a property file called message_fr the message appear ????????????, i don't know why ?

Answer (score 3):

Velocity Tools' [ResourceTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/ResourceTool.html) class is a tool for accessing ResourceBundles and formatting messages therein. An answer to a previous question describes [how to set up Velocity Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007863/how-to-xml-escaping-with-apache-velocity)

In the tools configuration file, add the following line to enable ResourceTool. You can provide a default locale, but normally the locale from `HttpServletRequest.getLocale()` will be used.

```
Toolbox configuration example:
 <tools>
   <toolbox scope="request">
     <tool class="org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ResourceTool"
              bundles="myresources"
              locale="en_US"/>
   </toolbox>
 </tools>
```

If your resource bundle contains

```
bar=The args are {0} and {1}.
```

you can use the following in your template

```
$text.bar                 ->  The args are {0} and {1}.
$text.bar.insert(4)       ->  The args are 4 and {1}.
$text.bar.insert(4,true)  ->  The args are 4 and true.
```

---

Maybe this is best shown using a fully programmatic configuration; this way you can manually set the locale each time.

```
EasyFactoryConfiguration config = new EasyFactoryConfiguration();
config.toolbox("request").tool(ResourceTool.class)
    .property("bundles", "myresources")
    .property("locale", "en_US");

ToolManager manager = new ToolManager(false, false);
manager.configure(config);

Context context = manager.createContext();
context.put("name", "Jarl");

Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("mytemplate.vm");

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
template.merge(context, writer);
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

mytemplate.vm:

```
$text.greeting $name
```

myresources_en_US.properties:

```
greeting=Hello
```

Output

```
Hello Jarl
```

Comment: can you give me more clarification for the above code, coz it's not clear to me.

Comment: Edited the answer for clarity, hope this helps.

Comment: what is com.foo.moreResources ? and to access a key in the property file is by $text.myKey ? and how does the toolbox to know which property file to read from the french or english ?

Comment: Okay, didn't realise before now that you needed to set up locale etc manually. Added example code, good luck.

Comment: in my case i am using model instead of context, how would i handle this , and is there's a dependency for this toolbox ?

Comment: and what will be the value for myresources in property("bundles", "myresources")

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC comes with (very) useful velocimacros (see [Spring MVC documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-velocity)). One of them is #springMessageText.

In your hello.vm file:

```
<span>#springMessageText("hi.message", "Hello Default!")</span>
```

This macro will read the message from your message sources, depending on the current locale (using the built-in [ResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ResourceBundleMessageSource.html) from Spring).

messages_fr_FR.properties

```
hi.message=Bonjour
```

messages_en_GB.propertie

```
hi.message=Hello
```

If no bundle is available for the current locale, the default message "Hello Default!" is used.

By default, Spring is reading messages*.properties files. But you can specify more message sources in your servlet.xml configuration (here, messages*.properties and othermessages*.properties):

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
      <list>
        <value>messages</value>
        <value>othermessages</value>
      </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

**How does SpringMVC knows about the current locale?**

Well, it's all built-in SpringMVC. The ResourceBundleMessageSource reads keys according to the Locale.
I think a LocaleResolver is configured by default (using the locale sent along the client request), but you can [register your own localeResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-localeresolver).

I encourage you to check all the available [springmvc velocimacros](https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/spring.vm) and [velocity tools](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic.html) (very useful!).

Comment: i am really confused, and i need a little more help, maybe a sample, about how to use it in my vm

Comment: what if i don't want to put a default value for the key ?

Comment: the use the #springMessage velocimacro (see https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/spring.vm )

Comment: thanks, but how will the vm knows that the current locale is fr or it so that he will read from equivalent property file ?

Comment: i followed the above instructions but when i used this <span>#springMessage("hi.message")</span> in my vm, it appears <span>#springMessageText("hi.message", "Hello Default!")</span>
instead of dynamic text as i expected, is there's something missing here ?

Comment: hint, i am using vm in sending emails

Comment: edited my question ffor hints about springmvc locale resolution.

Comment: you didin't tell me why the message doesn't appear, is there's something i am missing here, like an import to spring.vm ?

Comment: velocity is not my view technology used in the app, i am using it's templates in sending emails only.

Comment: @Brian Clozel, ping here! , why can't i use the method #springMessageText in my vm template

Comment: I guess you have to configure your velocityEngine to include the spring.vm velocimacros. For further enquiries, you should ask another question, otherwise answers won't show up for other users.

Answer (score 1):

this is because of your encoding, try at first to manually change the page encoding (usually in tools).

i got a bit farther in this but not much farther..Spring automatically sets the encoding to iso-8859-1, i made it set it to utf-8, however, my hebrew strings changed to gibrish, also destroyed the chance to hand-pick the right encoding as none of em seem to decode it right.

i'd really appreciate a hand in solving this problem.