# Unable to use macros with velocity in email templates?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

greetings all
i am using velocity templates when sending emails
and i want to read texts dynamically from property files depending on user locale

the xml config:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">

     <property name="basenames">
     <list>
     <value>classpath:messages</value>
     <value>classpath:messages_ar</value>
     </list>
     </property>

    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
            <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</prop>
            <prop key="velocimacro.library">org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/spring.vm</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
<property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/classes/com/spacerdv/mailTemplates"/>
</bean>


    <!-- 

  View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
  different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.

   -->

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
  <property name="cache" value="true"/>
  <property name="prefix" value=""/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
  <!-- if you want to use the Spring Velocity macros, set this property to true -->
  <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

and when trying to read the text from property file like :

```
<span>#springMessage("hi.message")</span>
```

it doesn't read any thing, or prints the default value, just prints:

```
$springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code)
```

i don't know why? , am i missing something ?, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macros can't be used outside web app like in email templates, so a solution would be to pass messageSource to the vm file and read from the property file by it like the answer in here:

[Is it possible to read static text dynamically from property files in velocity template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322783/is-it-possible-to-read-static-text-dynamically-from-property-files-in-velocity-te)

Answer (score 10):

When using the velocity engine for sending emails, you may have to configure your engine tu use the velocimacro librabry shipped within spring.

```
<bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
  <property name="velocityProperties">
    <props>
      <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
        <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</prop>
        <prop key="velocimacro.library">org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/spring.vm</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

You can check [the example in spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html#mail-templates-example).

If Spring doesn't inject automatically the `$springMacroRequestContext` variable into your model, you should put it yourself:

```
model.put("springMacroRequestContext", new RequestContext(request, response, getServletContext(), model));
```

That's basically what they do in the [AbstractTemplateView](https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.web.servlet/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractTemplateView.java) class. I guess you won't be able to do it, since you're handling emails here, and not web requests. But that's definitely a hint on what you can do to get it working.

Comment: after i added applied the above config, the value appears now $springMacroRequestContext.getMessage($code) , what do you think ? and i do have another question, is where to define the property files for velocity to use ?

Comment: maybe because no property files are defined.
check out my other answer, it's there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322783/is-it-possible-to-read-static-text-dynamically-from-property-files-in-velocity-te/4322967#4322967

Comment: are you sure you need to specify "classpath:"? IMHO, you don't need to specify locales in this list either ("messages" alone should be fine)

Comment: do yo mean just <value>messages</value>, coz i tried it , and it didn't work.

Comment: then maybe it has something to do with:

'To take advantage of these macros, the "exposeSpringMacroHelpers" property of the VelocityView class needs to be set to "true". This will expose a RequestContext under the name "springMacroRequestContext", as needed by the macros in this library.'

I don't know how to configure this directly into the engine. Again, please edit your question to reflect your comments (if you want it to be useful for others).

Comment: really i am very thankful for your big support, even if the problem is not solved

Comment: added a little something that may help you with this

Comment: where exactly to use this line model.put("springMacroRequestContext", new RequestContext(request, response, getServletContext(), model));

Comment: don't i need something like #parse("spring.vm") in the vm file ?

Comment: macros can't be used outside web app like in my case, so a solution would be to pass messageSource to the vm file and read by it , and i am posting another question about it

Comment: This worked perfect for me. I did need to put the springMacroRequestContext in manually as it did not get injected. Also, I think RequestContext's signature does not take a response, otherwise I put this in almost unchanged.

Comment: I managed to create a RequestContext for sending emails using the following:    model.put("springMacroRequestContext", new RequestContext(((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest(), null, null, null));