# Escape a curly brace { in Velocity

Tags: java, velocity

SORRY: This is my bad. This error is due incorrect json produce and to Chrome extension "JSONView in Chrome". See my own answer (I had to answer this myself - as I could not delete the question anymore).

I am using Velocity (Maven version 1.7 of org.apache.velocity) as templating engine, and I want output as follows:

```
{
   total : 234
}
```

now when I try:

```
{
    total : $listing.size()
}
```

I get an error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
{   total : 0}
--^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

[image]

and when I try to escape the curly braces:

```
\{
    total : $listing.size()
\}
```

I get the escape characters in the final output!:

```
\{
   total : 234
\}
```

Comment: Huh?  Velocity doesn't care about solitary braces.  They don't need escaping.  What version are you using? And can you show the rest of your parse error?

Comment: I am getting an error - I didn't make the rules. That is all of the error that I am getting in the little javascript popup window, which is wierd cause I see no js in the source.

Comment: I am using the version from Maven - org.apache.velocity 1.7

Comment: The brace on it's own really shouldn't be a problem, I have many templates which contain Javascript functions in them. What does your template look like prior to the first `{` ? Are there unterminated VTL macros or operators before this?

Comment: Updated my answer, but all comments to it somehow disappeared.

Comment: SORRY: This is my bad. This error is due to Chrome extension "JSONView in Chrome"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this was due incorrect JSON I was producing, which Chrome browser's extension "JSONView" pointed out to me. This was because my keys were not strings... i.e. I had:

```
 {total: 0}
```

but I should've had:

```
 {"total" : 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Indeed there is a better way of doing this.**

use the accepted answer here ([How to XML escaping with Apache Velocity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007863/how-to-xml-escaping-with-apache-velocity)) to do the initial set-up

you would need to add the velocity-tools dependency as well :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and then you can use the escape mechanism of the Velocity Engine like this (for your case)

```
$esc.java("{total: 0}")
```

you can also checkout more escape options here(http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html)

Comment: This is _the answer_ (if you're not working with ill-formed JSON ).  Works very nicely for escaping any and all velocity tokens, eg.  $escape.java("${project.version}")

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a constant `ocb = {` and `ccb = }` and using `$ocb` and `$ccb`.

I am sure there is a better way. ;)

Comment: Really? Is this engine really so bad... maybe I should back away while i still can

Comment: IMHO I find it is really cool. However, I was never one to spend too much time reading manuals.

Comment: SORRY: This is my bad. This error is due to Chrome extension "JSONView in Chrome"!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that looks like your situation:
http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#escapinginvalidvtlreferences

**UPDATE:**

Try to do this first:

```
#set( $startbrace = "{" )
#set( $endbrace = "}" )
```

and then make your text this:

```
$startbrace
    total : $listing.size()
$endbrace
```

Comment: SORRY: This is my bad. This error is due to Chrome extension "JSONView in Chrome"!